# Order by deleted timestamp and return records starting from specific id

Tags: mysql, laravel

I have a `messages` table, and I want to get the deleted messages. They are determined by not null timestamp, and I want them starting from user-specified `id`. First I thought that this would be just a simple query (I use 48 as example):

```
select id from messages where deleted_at <> "NULL" and id > 48 order by deleted_at;
```

Shortly I noticed that this does not return the expected result. Here are some results from my dataset:

```
    # without id > 48
    46,54,53,52,51,50,49,48,61,63,62

    # with id > 48
    49,50,51,52,53,54,61,62,63

    # so I just want to cut the result from a specified value, like so
    46,54,53,52,51,50,49,48 V 61,63,62
                            % *snip*

    # expected result
    61,63,62
```

(I added the scissors to illustrate the problem)

How can I build a query to do so? I am also open for a Laravel-only solution, but just getting a SQL way would be good. I know the limiting could be done with Laravel-side PHP scripting, but it has a great cost when this data is pinged once per second.

Answer (score 1):

NULL is not a String

```
select id from messages where deleted_at is not null and id > 48 order by deleted_at;
```

Comment: This does not solve my problem, my query is sorting the nulls and timestamps fine. I am using Laravel framework, which may be the reason why they are not "real" nulls.

Comment: Are you using Eloquent? Model::whereNotNull('deleted_at').where("id", ">", "48")...

Comment: Oh yes, but I already know about `whereNotNull` and even have had some tests with it

Answer (score 0):

With Laravel, you can use `WhereNotNull`, e.g.:

```
$messages = DB::table('messages')
                    ->whereNotNull('deleted_at')
                    ->orderBy('deleted_at', 'desc')
                    ->get();
```

Comment: You didn't even understand my question. I know how to do this, but what I am asking is to cut the series by id (possibly with `limit` keyword or something). I already know how to translate this for Laravel when I know how to do the base query.